# Woocommerce product vendors - customize vendor landing page

Tags: woocommerce, customization, product, vendor

Am using WooCommerce Product vendors plugin.  https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/

I would like to customize the Vendor landing page on the Store.

Basically I want to write my own class - WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend

How do I do this. 
TIA

Comment: Hi JoeDennis you have to provide more information about what you've already tried and search in stackoverflow previous answers. Thanks

Comment: From my research it is possible to override anything under templates folder for any woocommerce plugin. But this happens to be a class in includes folder. I am new to woocommerce and i do not understand how to override a class or a method inside includes folder.  I tried to override the method inside functions.php but did not work!